# retrieve/debug current FPS after regulating it?

Tags: c++, sdl, frame-rate

i want my game to run on multiple computers around my house at a fixed FPS.  i have a simple question: how do i debug my current fps

i am regulating my fps like this:

```
SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING);
const unsigned FPS = 20;
Uint32 start = SDL_GetTicks(); // How much time (milliseconds) has passed after SDL_Init was called.

while (true)
{
  start = SDL_GetTicks();

  if (1000 / FPS > SDL_GetTicks() - start)
    SDL_Delay(1000 / FPS - (SDL_GetTicks() - start)); // Delays program in milliseconds
```

i think that should regulate my fps.  the question is, how do i get the current fps?

i tried

```
std::stringstream fps;
fps << 1000 / FPS - (SDL_GetTicks() - start);
SDL_WM_SetCaption(fps.str().c_str(), NULL); // Set the window caption
```

and

```
fps << start / 1000; // and vice versa
```

but none of them gave me what i wanted.

Comment: Seen this? http://gafferongames.com/game-physics/fix-your-timestep/

Comment: no but it looks really interesting.  i will read this.  thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Give this block a shot:

```
while(true)
{
    // render
    // logic
    // etc...

    // calculate (milli-)seconds per frame and frames per second
    static unsigned int frames = 0;
    static Uint32 start = SDL_GetTicks();
    Uint32 current = SDL_GetTicks();
    Uint32 delta = (current - start);
    frames++;
    if( delta > 1000 )
    {
        float seconds = delta / 1000.0f;
        float spf = seconds / frames;
        float fps = frames / seconds;
        cout << "Milliseconds per frame: " << spf * 1000 << endl;
        cout << "Frames per second: " << fps << endl;
        cout << endl;

        frames = 0;
        start = current;
    }
}
```

Note that `uint / uint` will result in a `uint`, while `uint / float` is a `float`.